# New IMG title disappears when changing via javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an  image that changes its src onclick. This functionality works fine, but I need to change the img title attribute as well. My code changes the title but only keeps the change while hovering my mouse over the img.

When I onmouseout of the img, FF Developer shows the title reverting to empty, ultimately not saving the new img title. Thought it was a browser issue but other browsers do the same.

Ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function my_func() {
    if (document.getElementById("changeable").src == "mysrc") {
      document.getElementById("changeable").src = "newsrc";
      document.getElementById("changeable").setAttribute("title","Now showing newimg");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("changeable").src = "newimg";
      document.getElementById("changeable").setAttribute("title","Now showing defaultimg");
    }
  }
</script>
<img id="changeable" onclick="my_func();" src="mysrc" title="Click to toggle" />
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.setAttribute()` to set the "title" property. You can set it directly, the same way you're setting "src".

Comment: It's likely that you have some other code on the same page conflicting with it. My guess would be tooltip libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You checked condition wrong,

Here,
document.getElementById("changeable").src result should be "file:///home/system/Desktop/mysrc"

use like,

```html
<html><script type="text/javascript">
  function my_func() {
    if (document.getElementById("changeable").getAttribute('src') == "mysrc") {
      document.getElementById("changeable").setAttribute('src',"newsrc");
      document.getElementById("changeable").setAttribute("title","Now showing newimg");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("changeable").src = "newimg";
      document.getElementById("changeable").setAttribute("title","Now showing defaultimg");
    }
  }
</script>
<img id="changeable" onclick="my_func();" src="mysrc" title="Click to toggle" />
</html>
```